# How SC_CTOR works in SystemC

Tags: c++11, systemc, opencpu

In SystemC module constructor can be defined using `SC_CTOR` macro:

```
#define SC_MODULE(user_module_name)                   \
    struct user_module_name : ::sc_core::sc_module

#define SC_CTOR(user_module_name)                     \
    typedef user_module_name SC_CURRENT_USER_MODULE;  \
    user_module_name( ::sc_core::sc_module_name )
```

Need to understand use scope specifier operator before `sc_core`.
As per the macro user can generate constructor but it takes argument `sc_module_name`.

User module `struct user module` is inheriting class `sc_module`, In class `sc_module` there are different overloaded constructor like

```
sc_module();
sc_module( const sc_module_name& nm ); /* for those used to old style */

/* DEPRECATED */ sc_module( const char* nm );
/* DEPRECATED */ sc_module( const std::string& nm );
```

As per `SC_CTOR` it is declaring any object of type sc_moduke_name in constructor body if expanded the constructor will take form `user_module(::sc_core::sc_module) { /*constructor body*/}`.
To understand simulate same code but failed to create object of type struct B

```
class mname {
    private:
            char *name;
    public:
            mname() {
                    cout << "mname constructor invoked\n";
                    cout << "\t name\t" << name;
            }
};

class A {
    friend class mname;
    private:
    mname * mn;
    public:
    A() {
            cout << "A constructor called\n";
    }
    A(const mname& m) {
            cout << "freind class constructor of A\n";
    }
    A(const std:: string& s) {
            cout << "string type construfctor\n";
    }
};

struct B: A {
    B(mname ) {
            cout     << "struct b cosntructor called\n";
    }

};

int main() {

    B obj(mname);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A typical code to create a module is :

```
SC_MODULE(my_module)
{
   SC_CTOR(my_module)
   {

   }
};
```

With macros, this code will expand to:

```
struct my_module : ::sc_core::sc_module
{
   typedef my_module SC_CURRENT_USER_MODULE;
   my_module( ::sc_core::sc_module_name )
   {

   }
};
```

If you want to create an instance of this module, you need to pass an instance of `::sc_core::sc_module_name` in the constructor and not the class name as you did in your example code. You can also pass something to create implicitly an instance of `::sc_core::sc_module_name` as a `const char*` (cf `::sc_core::sc_module_name` constructors)

```
my_module a("name_of_my_module");
```

or

```
::sc_core::sc_module_name module_name("another_name");
my_module b(module_name);
```

In your example code, just replace the main with :

```
int main() {
    mname name; // instance of mname
    B obj(name);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is one more query as struct my_module has defined only one constructor which is taking sc_module_name instance then how const char* implicitly create instance of sc_module_name. As per my understanding for this there will be one more constructor of type my_module(const char*) . May be not good in C++ concepts, Thanks in advance to provide some more  details

Comment: I understand the point that when char* is passed then sc_module is friend of sc_module_name, sc_module_name already defined constructor with char* argument but another issue is if sc_module_name creates constructor with two arguments sc_module_name(const char*, int)  and when try to create B object like b obj("another name", 4) then it fails